# Solving Time dependent Schrodinger equation using MATLAB ode45

Tags: matlab, computational-physics, quantum-mechanics, octave, maple

The Schrodinger equation for time-dependent Hamiltonian is

$$i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}\psi(t) = H(t)\psi(t) \, .$$

I try to implement solve the Schrodinger equation for time-dependent Hamiltonian in ODE 45. However, because the Hamiltonian $H(t)$ is dependent on time, I do not know how to do interpolation in ode45. Can you give me some hints?

```
psi0 = [0 1];
H = [1 0;0 1]*cos(t); %this is wrong, I do not know how to implement this and pass it to ode45
hbar = 1;
t    = [0:1:100];
[T, psi] = ode45(dpsi, t, psi);
function dpsi = f(t, psi, H, psi0)
dpsi = (1/i)*H*psi;
```

Comment: Try the MATLAB ODE function ode15s instead of ode45, http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode15s.html. You can specifiy a time-dependent "mass" matrix with ode15s.

Comment: Thanks. I also heard that mass matrix can be defined for ode45 by adding extra row. Is that true?

Comment: @kww why do you think there is a need to explicitly pass $H(t)$ into your ode45 call? You can just have the definition for $H(t)$ inside your function "dpsi". dpsi receives the current time stamp as one of its parameters.

Comment: Yes, according to the documentation, Mass, is also a valid option for the ode45 function, so you can pass a mass matrix function if you choose.

Comment: @Bill Greene Could you give me some hints on how to pass the mass matrix to ode45? if I pass it, do i need to do interpolation?

Comment: The option for passing a mass matrix is "Mass" documented here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html

Comment: @Bill Greene I still do not quite understand mass matrix. We have M(t,y) y'=f(t,y). If f(t,y) has y and t in it, what is the purpose of M(t,y)?

Comment: Apparently I misunderstood your question. I thought you were looking for a convenient way to deal with the $ih$ term in your equation. Mass matrix would be useful for that. But after more careful reading, I am not sure what your question is. I have no experience with Schrodinger equation and your post doesn't provide much information. Is $\psi$ a vector of length two?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's a cross-post of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37981618/solving-time-dependent-schrodinger-equation-using-matlab-ode45, and cross-posting is frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this is what you want?

```
function schrodingerEqn
psi0 = [0 1];
hbar = 1;
t    = [0:1:100];
fh = @(t, psi) f(t, psi, hbar);
[T, psi] = ode45(fh, t, psi0);
figure; plot(T, real(psi(:,2)));
end

function dpsi = f(t, psi, hbar)
dpsi = 1/(hbar*i)*[1 0;0 1]*cos(t)*psi;
end
```